# Получить наименование родительской ветки

Tags: git

В проекте есть основные ветки `develop` и `stable`. В некоторых случаях ветки каждой отдельной фичи создавались от `develop`, а в некоторых от `stable`, но теперь понадобилось узнать про одну из старых фичей, от какой ветки она была создана. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В общем случае никак. Можно посмотреть `git log --graph --all` или в каком-нибудь графическом git-просмотрщике и глазками понять. Обычно по графу это видно, но формализовать условия сложно

Comment: @Alexey Ten пробовал но он огромный там черт ногу сломит а проще способа нет чтобы просто получать название ветки.

Comment: Ветка это просто указатель на верхний коммит. Можно поискать общего родителя ветки и develop/master и посмотреть кто «старше» (см git merge-base)

Comment: @Pavel, ветка в программе *git* — это не «некая последовательность коммитов», а всего лишь (плавающий) **указатель** на один-единственный коммит. информация о том, на какой именно коммит в какой момент времени указывал данный указатель в прошлом, увы не хранится (да, есть локальный reflog, может быть он чем-то вам и поможет).

Comment: что говорит git show --summary 'git merge-base ветка-фичи stable' и git show --summary 'git merge-base ветка-фичи develop' - только поменяйте ' на апострофы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как такового встроенного решения такой проблемы в git нет, но комбинируя git с bash  можно найти сразу несколько потенциальных решений проблемы:

1. `git branch --contains develop | grep "brach_name"` - эта команда сначала найдет все ветки созданные от develop, затем с помощью grep отфильтрует в поисках искомой ветки. Если указанной ветки нет среди веток, созданных от develop - вывод будет пустой, иначе выведется само имя ветки. При этом переходить на искомую ветку не нужно.
2. Вариант по-сложней:

   ```
   git show-branch -a \
   | grep '\*' \
   | grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
   | head -n1 \
   | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' \
   | sed 's/[\^~].*//'
   ```

   Выводим список всех веток вообще, далее, с помощью консольной магии ищем родителя ветки. Требует перехода на ветку, для которой ищем родителя.

Сразу оговорюсь, что решения проверялись исключительно на mac OS, но учитывая схожесть bash с Unix/Linux там также должно работать без изменений. Под Windows можно несложно сделать схожие команды. Больше информации и решений можно посмотреть в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch) на SO.